# How can I capture naturally created static electricity so that it won't create a shock when I touch a grounded object

Tags: device, antistatic, static

How can I capture the naturally created static electricity in our bodies, so that it won't create a shock when I touch a grounded object.

I'd like to capture it and store it for future use, maybe wire in an LED, buzzer, or cell phone...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronics design.

Answer (score 3):

That static electricity is created from rubbing against objects in the environment, which causes charges to be transferred in what is called the [triboelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect). The total amount of charge is small, but the voltage can easily be in the 10s of kilovolts range. While there are electrochemical potentials created inside the body by nerves and muscles, these potentials are on the order of millivolts, and can be a challenge to measure, let alone use as an energy source.

The human body is fairly conductive, and as the static charge builds up, it tends to distribute itself on the surface of the skin. The end result is that the whole body is charged to the same potential, and no current flows. Even after building up a static charge, a voltmeter across any two points of your body would read 0. Any device you were carrying would also be unable to detect or use any potential difference across your body. Like a circuit hooked up to only one terminal of a battery, no current could flow, and no energy could be harvested. It is the difference in potential that matters, and that only exists between the body and the environment.

One hypothetical way to collect the stored energy would be a device with two terminals. While holding one terminal, touch the doorknob with the other terminal. The discharge now takes place through the device, which can store some of the associated energy. While physically conceivable, I know of no device able to efficiently capture the energy from such an event. The currents and voltages are brief, but fairly extreme.

That said, at least one group has demonstrations of harvesting triboelectricity in a more controlled setting: [Paper Generators: Harvesting Energy from Touching, Rubbing and Sliding](http://www.disneyresearch.com/project/paper-generators/). Karagozler, M. E., Poupyrev, I., Fedder, G. K., and Suzuki, Y., In Proc. of UIST’13, ACM.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a way to 'not get shocked' when I have a static buildup in my body and touch something that is grounded.  I thought that collecting / storing the electricity would be the way to go, but maybe using it up as it's collected with a LED would also work.

Comment: Could a device that is not always in constant contact with our skin but only occasionally touch it to make the connection work?  A bracelet or bangle comes to mind where the connection are spaced out so that both are rarely in constant contact.

Comment: @user33043, If all you want is to not get shocked, try firmly holding a metal object such as a key, and touching the doorknob with that. As the key gets closer to the knob, the charges distributed across your body are attracted to the opposite charges in the knob, and collect in the end of the key. When the spark finally happens, the current is most concentrated in the key where you can't feel it. Another trick, and the one I use most often, is to touch the knob with the back of your wrist. There are fewer sensory neurons there, so you won't feel it as much.

Comment: A work colleague used to get static shocks when getting out of his car. He solved it by letting his wife get out first.